# Multiple actionbar master/detail (one for master and one for detail)

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, android-activity, master-detail

I'm trying to create an application using the Master/Detail Flow template provided by Android.
I'm trying to add multiple actionbar menu items to both the master and detail portions of the actionbar.

[image]

I have use the example of Android studio but when i set the different menu for master e for detail, is show only the menu (to right) .

the Activity detail is:

```
public class PDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_p_detail);

    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // savedInstanceState is non-null when there is fragment state
    // saved from previous configurations of this activity
    // (e.g. when rotating the screen from portrait to landscape).
    // In this case, the fragment will automatically be re-added
    // to its container so we don't need to manually add it.
    // For more information, see the Fragments API guide at:
    //
    // http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
    //
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Create the detail fragment and add it to the activity
        // using a fragment transaction.
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(PDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, getIntent().getStringExtra(PatientDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID));
        PatientDetailFragment fragment = new PDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.p_detail_container, fragment).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_p_detail, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        navigateUpTo(new Intent(this, PListActivity.class));
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

the fragment detail is:

```
public class PDetailFragment extends Fragment {
/**
 * The fragment argument representing the item ID that this fragment
 * represents.
 */
public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "item_id";

/**
 * The dummy content this fragment is presenting.
 */
private PObj mItem;

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public PDetailFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    ((PatientDetailActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Detail");

    if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
        // Load the dummy content specified by the fragment
        // arguments. In a real-world scenario, use a Loader
        // to load content from a content provider.
        mItem = PListFragment.pObjHashMap.get(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_p_detail, container, false);

    // Show the dummy content as text in a TextView.
    if (mItem != null) {
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.p_detail)).setText(mItem.name);
    }

    return rootView;
}
}
```

The activity master:

```
public class PListActivity extends BaseActivity implements PListFragment.Callbacks {

/**
 * Whether or not the activity is in two-pane mode, i.e. running on a tablet
 * device.
 */
private boolean mTwoPane;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_p_list);



    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    //        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    if (findViewById(R.id.p_detail_container) != null) {
        // The detail container view will be present only in the
        // large-screen layouts (res/values-large and
        // res/values-sw600dp). If this view is present, then the
        // activity should be in two-pane mode.
        mTwoPane = true;

        // In two-pane mode, list items should be given the
        // 'activated' state when touched.
        ((PListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.p_list))
                .setActivateOnItemClick(true);
    }

    // TODO: If exposing deep links into your app, handle intents here.
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_p, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
 //            navigateUpFromSameTask(this);


        SharedPreferenceObj sp = MySharedPref.getSharedPref(getApplicationContext());
        sp.setLast_id_office(StaticValues.ID);
        MySharedPref.setSharedPref(getApplicationContext(), sp);

        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * Callback method from {@link PListFragment.Callbacks}
 * indicating that the item with the given ID was selected.
 */
@Override
public void onItemSelected(String id) {

    if (mTwoPane) {
        // In two-pane mode, show the detail view in this activity by
        // adding or replacing the detail fragment using a
        // fragment transaction.
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(PatientDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        PatientDetailFragment fragment = new PDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.p_detail_container, fragment)
                .commit();

    } else {
        // In single-pane mode, simply start the detail activity
        // for the selected item ID.
        Intent dIntent = new Intent(this, PDetailActivity.class);
        dIntent.putExtra(PDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        startActivity(dIntent);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    SharedPreferenceObj sp = MySharedPref.getSharedPref(getApplicationContext());
    sp.setLast_id_office(StaticValues.ID);
    MySharedPref.setSharedPref(getApplicationContext(),sp);
    super.onBackPressed();

}
}
```

the fragment master is:

```
public class PListFragment extends ListFragment {
//DummyContent dummyContent ;

public static List<PObj> pObjArrayList = new ArrayList<PObj>();
public static Map<String, PObj> pObjHashMap = new HashMap<String, PObj>();

/**
 * The serialization (saved instance state) Bundle key representing the
 * activated item position. Only used on tablets.
 */
private static final String STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION = "activated_position";

/**
 * The fragment's current callback object, which is notified of list item
 * clicks.
 */
private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;

/**
 * The current activated item position. Only used on tablets.
 */
private int mActivatedPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;

/**
 * A callback interface that all activities containing this fragment must
 * implement. This mechanism allows activities to be notified of item
 * selections.
 */
public interface Callbacks {
    /**
     * Callback for when an item has been selected.
     */
    public void onItemSelected(String id);
}

/**
 * A dummy implementation of the {@link Callbacks} interface that does
 * nothing. Used only when this fragment is not attached to an activity.
 */
private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {

    }
};

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public PListFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    ((PListActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Master");
    pObjArrayList.clear();
    pObjHashMap.clear();
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        patientObjArrayList.add(new PObj(i+"","name"+i,"address"+i));
        patientObjHashMap.put(i+"",new PObj(i+"","name"+i,"address"+i));
    }
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<PObj>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
            android.R.id.text1, patientObjArrayList));
    // TODO: replace with a real list adapter.

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // Restore the previously serialized activated item position.
    if (savedInstanceState != null
            && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION)) {
        setActivatedPosition(savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION));
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {

    super.onAttach(context);
    Activity activity = (Activity) context;
    // Activities containing this fragment must implement its callbacks.
    if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
    }

    mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    // Reset the active callbacks interface to the dummy implementation.
    mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);

    // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
    // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
    mCallbacks.onItemSelected(pObjArrayList.get(position).id);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (mActivatedPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        // Serialize and persist the activated item position.
        outState.putInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION, mActivatedPosition);
    }
}

/**
 * Turns on activate-on-click mode. When this mode is on, list items will be
 * given the 'activated' state when touched.
 */
public void setActivateOnItemClick(boolean activateOnItemClick) {
    // When setting CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, ListView will automatically
    // give items the 'activated' state when touched.
    getListView().setChoiceMode(activateOnItemClick
            ? ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE
            : ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
}

private void setActivatedPosition(int position) {
    if (position == ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        getListView().setItemChecked(mActivatedPosition, false);
    } else {
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }

    mActivatedPosition = position;
}

}
```

The problem is that i show only one menu (master) and no the menu (detail)
in this screenshot 
[image]

in this screenshot I have only one menu and the + is on the right instead of the left next to the title "Master".
In the part relating to the detail is missing from the title and even the symbol X.

how can fix my problem?